# Questions about Rings and properties of GCD

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose I have a ring $R$ and suppose if I am given two elements $x, y$ that are relatively prime to each other, or their $gcd(x,y)=1$. from this, can it be concluded knowing nothing else about the ring $R$ that it contains the identity element and hence some or all elements contains its own inverse?

Thank you in dvance

Comment: What would $\gcd(x,y)=1$ mean if you didn't already have $1$ in the ring?

Comment: @Arthur so does that mean if a ring $R$ don't contains the identity element, then any two elements in the ring $R$ can never be relatively prime??

Comment: @Arthur It could mean $\,d\mid x,y\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid r,\,$ for all $\,r\in R\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I agree that that's a way to formulate coprimality. So that notion makes sense. But how would it make sense to say that $1$ is a divisor of $x$ and $y$ if $1$ isn't in the ring? Because that's implied by $\gcd(x,y)=1$ to me.